# Android Compose Google Test Crash

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've been having this issues since the first version of the application. As far as I can see, Google using a tool to run the tests on the Compose applications. There is a few crashes are happening that I see on Firebase Crashlytics when the application is "In Review" stage. Here are the crashes:

- Fatal Exception: androidx.compose.runtime.ComposeRuntimeError: Compose Runtime internal error. Unexpected or incorrect use of the Compose internal runtime API (Cannot reposition while in an empty region). Please report to Google or use https://goo.gle/compose-feedback

> ```
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.composeRuntimeError(Composer.kt:4383)
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.SlotReader.reposition(SlotTable.kt:3448)
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2348)
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2666)
>    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(NavHost.kt:164)
>    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(NavHost.kt:141)
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
>    at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$5$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:133)
>    at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$5$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:128)
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
>    at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt.Crossfade(Crossfade.kt:142)
>    at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$7.invoke(:17)
>    at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$7.invoke(:8)
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:145)
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2375)
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2643)
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3260)
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3238)
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(:1)
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3238)
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3203)
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:771)
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:1031)
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:125)
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:534)
>    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:503)
>    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:34)
>    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
>    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
>    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
>    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1035)
>    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:845)
>    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:775)
>    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1022)
>    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
>    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
>    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
> ```

- Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.Messenger.send(android.os.Message)' on a null object reference

> ```
>    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.handleOverlayServiceRequest(RemotePlatform.java:6)
>    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.messageLoop(RemotePlatform.java:48)
>    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.lambda$startCrawlAndWaitUntilFinished$0$androidx-test-tools-crawler-platform-RemotePlatform(RemotePlatform.java:1)
>    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(:6)
>    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
> ```

Since I know this is only happening in Google's review process it's okay but still disturbs me to see this. Anyone has faced with this issue and have a proper solution for this?

P.S: I use compose dependencies with BOM file (**version: 2022.12.00**)